# Python class return types

Tags: python, class, methods, types

I was wondering if anyone could help me with something.
If I have a class that has an attribute is there a way to automatically make an object of that class return that attribute whenever it is called

```
class Constant():
def __init__(self, value):
    self.__value = value
PI = Constant(3.14)
```

Is there any way for it to return 3.14 (as an actual float not a string) without explicitly defining the `__float__` method and calling `float(PI)`.  I want to be able to just say something along the lines of `print(PI*2)` and to get `6.28` as my output

EDIT:
I found what I wanted, by using the `__new__` method i can change the return value from an instance to whatever I want.

2nd EDIT:
turns out that didn't work.

Comment: `self.__value = float(value)` is it working?

Comment: @Tserenjamts __value is the correct 'value' (couldn't think of another word), the problem is returning it wherever PI is called almost like a macro, I want PI to be like a float variable except for a bit more control internally

Comment: https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: Why would you even *have* this class, if you want to automatically replace its instances with some other object whenever you attempt to do anything with the instance?

Comment: @Boris are you saying to just individually implement each method?

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones In my answer i implemented `__mul__` do the same for all other methods as well

Comment: @user2357112 because I can limit the user's ability to access/change the value along with providing other methods for it.

Comment: @U10-Forward I see thank you! I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones Please check my answer it's easier now!

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones Now it's even shorter and all float functions can work.

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones: But... if you had this automatic replacement functionality you're asking for, you *wouldn't* be able to do any of that enforcement, and you *wouldn't* be able to provide extra methods. Even if you defined some `foo` method on your class, you wouldn't be able to do `PI.foo()`, because `PI` would be replaced by `3.14` and `3.14` doesn't have a `foo` method.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't want it to actually automatically replace it.  I want wherever it sees PI without any method call attached to just return 3.14.

Comment: First, that's fundamentally incompatible with Python's execution model. Second, you'll find that the cases where you want to "just return 3.14" aren't as clear-cut as you think. For example, you wouldn't be able to pass instances of your class to other functions, because `foo(PI)` is "PI without any method call attached". You'd also have trouble accessing `float` methods like `is_integer`, because `PI.is_integer()` has a "method call attached".

Comment: ``PI * 3.14`` *implies* a method call -- to the ``type(PI).__mul__`` method. Doing practically *anything* with a Python object implies a method call. Please define clearly when you want this to resolve to the value and when not. Also take note that it is extremely trivial to modify the value of your ``Constant`` class.

Comment: "I found what I wanted, by using the ``__new__`` method" If you override ``__new__`` to return the value, why do you have the class in the first place? ``PI`` will never be an instance of ``Constant``, it will be a regular ``float``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ya I realized that.  I ended up making subclasses of the type of value and then just having a second superclass that made all of the `__i...__` methods produce an error

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones: But `float` doesn't *have* any in-place operations, or any mutator methods at all. Your objects are no less mutable than an ordinary `float`, and may be *more* mutable. You've made `PI *= 2` raise an error, but not `PI = PI * 2`, and if you still have a `__value` attribute, your `__value` can be reassigned, unlike a normal float. (By the way, if you're subclassing `float`, you don't need a separate `self.__value` holding a float. `self` is a float, and it's the one that matters.)

Comment: @user2357112 I see...

Answer (score 4):

Try subclassing `float`:

```
class Constant(float):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value
PI = Constant(3.14)
print(PI*2)
```

Output:

```
6.28
```

Comment: This would only work for multiplication.. I think @Owen Mehta-Jones is looking for something that lets them treat PI as a number.

Comment: @LocalhostNotfound Now?

Comment: That's a lot better, but I was hoping to make this work with multiple datatypes, unless I just make subclasses for each type...?

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones which other types?

Comment: @U10-Forward basically any of the built-in types.

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones You shouldn't, `float` is to treat the class as a float.

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones If you want more functions, just create your own functions and add it to the class.

Comment: @U10-Forward so then should I just make an overarching `Constant` class and have a subclass for each datatype I want?

Comment: @U10-Forward I'm not sure what you mean by if I want more functions?

Comment: @OwenMehta-Jones What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: How do you DM??

Comment: Nvm it says "automatically move this discussion to chat?" but when i click on it it doesnt let me

Comment: @U10-Forward back to the questions, do you think I could just have it inherit from all the types i want to use and then just call super on the actual type of value?

Comment: @U10-Forward is that how super works? im not entirely sure

Comment: The `__init__` method here is unnecessary, and the `__value` attribute is misleading. You now have two separate representations of your data, one as `self` and one as `self.__value`. These representations can easily go out of sync, leading to nasty bugs. You can just take out `__init__` and `__value` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for accessing a private variable

```
class Constant():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value

PI = Constant(3.14)
print(PI._Constant__value*2)
```

```
6.28
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  If I really wanted I would make an `@property` method and just make the user put in PI.val every time, but I want a constant class where you can just call the object and get the value in return.